# How to parametrize $\Lambda$CDM using six independent parameters?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

It is well-known that the $\Lambda$CDM model has six independent parameters.
For example, the Planck collaboration (e. g. [Planck 2018 results](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209)) quotes the following independent parameters in their results:
“[…]

- the baryon density $\omega_{\mathrm{b}} = \Omega_{\mathrm{b}} h^2$,
- cold dark matter density $\omega_{\mathrm{c}} = \Omega_{\mathrm{c}} h^2$,
- an approximation to the observed angular size of the sound horizon at recombination $\theta_{\mathrm{MC}}$,
- the reionization optical depth $\tau$,
- the initial super-horizon amplitude of curvature perturbations $A_{\mathrm{s}}$ at $k = 0.05 \,\mathrm{Mpc}^{-1}$,
- and the primordial spectral index $n_{\mathrm{s}}$.

However, while these were probably chosen for good reasons, it’s not entirely clear to me how they relate to a more “naive” set of parameters.

[WMAP](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5226) uses a slightly different set of parameters, which seem to match my expectations more closely:
“The six parameters of the basic $\Lambda$CDM model are:

- the physical baryon density, $\Omega_{\mathrm{b}} h^2$;
- the physical cold dark matter density, $\Omega_{\mathrm{c}} h^2$;
- the dark energy density, in units of the critical density, $\Omega_\Lambda$;
- the amplitude of primordial scalar curvature perturbations, $\Delta_{\mathcal{R}}^2$ at $k = 0.002 \,\mathrm{Mpc}^{-1}$;
- the power-law spectral index of primordial density (scalar) perturbations, $n_{\mathrm{s}}$;
- and the reionization optical depth, $\tau$.

In this model, the Hubble constant, $H_0 = 100h \, \mathrm{km}/\mathrm{s}/\mathrm{Mpc}$, is implicitly determined by the flatness constraint, $\Omega_{\mathrm{b}} + \Omega_{\mathrm{c}} + \Omega_\Lambda = 1$.”

---

Here is what I would come up with:
Since we’re in the context of FLRW cosmology, here are the Friedmann equations
$$
H(t)^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho(t) - \frac{kc^2}{a(t)^2}
$$
$$
\dot{H}(t) + H(t)^2 = -\frac{4\pi G}{3} \left(\rho(t) + \frac{3p(t)}{c^2}\right)
$$
with $\rho = \rho_{\mathrm{r}} + \rho_{\mathrm{c}} + \rho_{\mathrm{b}} - \frac{\Lambda c^2}{8\pi G}$ and $p = p_{\mathrm{r}} + p_{\mathrm{c}} + p_{\mathrm{b}} + \frac{\Lambda c^4}{8\pi G}$.
The pressure is related to the density via the equations of state $\rho_i = w_i \rho_i c^2$, and $\Lambda$CDM assumes $k = 0$, so that’s out.
Given that, in total, 5 quantities appear in the Friedmann equations: $H$, $\rho_{\mathrm{r}}$, $\rho_{\mathrm{c}}$, $\rho_{\mathrm{b}}$, and $\Lambda$. Since the second equation is a differential equation for $H(t)$, we need to have initial values for the 5 quantities to solve for the evolution of $H(t)$ (as well as the evolution of the densities $\rho_i(t) = \rho_{i, 0} a(t)^{-3 (1 + w_i)}$), corresponding to $H_0$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{c}}$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{b}}$, and $\Omega_\Lambda$.
Using additionally the first Friedmann equation in the form
$$
\Omega_{\mathrm{r}} + \Omega_{\mathrm{c}} + \Omega_{\mathrm{b}} + \Omega_\Lambda = 1
$$
(since $k = 0$), we can eliminate one of the $\Omega_i$, e. g. $\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}$.
Coming back to the WMAP/Planck parameters, while this goes beyond the Friedmann equations, I can see why the two parameters for the normalization and shape of the power spectrum ($A_{\mathrm{s}}$ and $n_{\mathrm{s}}$) would be needed.

So we have six parameters in total and everything seems to look good: $H_0$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{c}}$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{b}}$, $\Omega_\Lambda$, $A_{\mathrm{s}}$, $n_{\mathrm{s}}$.
Five of them are even (almost) the same as the WMAP ones!

So, I suppose my question is:

1. Is this a valid parametrization of $\Lambda$CDM?
2. If so, how do $\tau$ (and $\theta$ for Planck) relate to $H_0$ (and $\Omega_\Lambda$)? How would one compute $H_0$ given the WMAP results for $\tau$ (along with the other parameters)?
3. I’m a bit confused by the WMAP statement that $H_0$ is determined from $\Omega_{\mathrm{b}} + \Omega_{\mathrm{c}} + \Omega_\Lambda = 1$. First of all, how does that work? And secondly, where did $\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}$ go? (Yes, I realize that its value is very small, but still.) It sounds a bit like I both have one parameter too many ($H_0$, since apparently they can determine that from the $\Omega_i$) and that I’m missing one ($\tau$).

Comment: about question 3): $H$ can be determined by the $\Omega_i$ since if $k=0$, you have $H^2=8 \pi G/ \rho /3$

Comment: @Yukterez Hm yes, but we don’t have $\rho$, just $\Omega_i$, don’t we? Sorry if I’m being dense, but I don’t see what numbers I could plug in here that would give me $H$.

Comment: We have the $\rho_r $ for the radiation and the $\rho_m$ for the matter and its proportion to the other $\rho_i$, so we get the $\Omega_i$ over $\Omega_i=\rho_i/(\rho_r+\rho_m+\rho_{\Lambda})$  since we know from the flattness $\rho_k=0$ that all the $\rho_i$ added together equal $\rho_{crit}=3H^3/(8\pi G)$

Comment: The reionization depth is not relevant in the FLRW since it is about the formation of the first stars, which would not take place in a perfectly homogenous and isotrope FLRW universe but you can use it to doublecheck if the density your other parameters give you for the given time matches the observed density for reinization

Comment: @Yukterez Alright, I hope I’m understanding correctly – basically we have 3 (or 4) equations $\Omega_i = \rho_i / \sum_j \rho_j$ and can use those to get the 3 (or 4) $\rho_i$, since the $\Omega_i$ are known, and then $\rho_{\mathrm{r}} + \rho_{\mathrm{m}} + \rho_\Lambda = 3 H^2/(8\pi G)$ gives us $H_0$?

Thanks for the clarification about $\tau$.

Comment: The whole input for the [FLRW evolution](http://flrw.yukterez.net) is shown [here](https://textbin.net/tdtzxocl5h), there you don't need the nₛ and τ for the large scale evolution